# Left JOIN with AND clause in ON with scalikejdbc

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, scalikejdbc

So I have this sql(part of a much larger query):

```
from Person p left join ForeignCredentials fc on fc.person_id = p.id and fc.type = 'FACEBOOK'
```

and I'm trying to represent this in scalalikejdbc like this:

```
select.from(Person as p).leftJoin(ForeignCredential as fc).on(fc.`person_id`, p.id)
```

But I can't figure out how to ad the extra condition. The intuitive way would be:

```
    select.from(Person as p).leftJoin(ForeignCredential as fc).on(fc.`person_id`, p.id)
.and.eq(fc.`type`, "FACEBOOK").
```

So how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work for you.

```
on(sqls.eq(fc.`person_id`, p.id).and.eq(fc.`type`, "FACEBOOK"))
```

https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/blob/2.2.8/scalikejdbc-interpolation/src/main/scala/scalikejdbc/QueryDSLFeature.scala#L408-L411